# GetBBox sizes of element returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to get the height and the width of a Snap SVG element in Javascript. When I try this, it returns 0 unless I add this element to a group. For this I am using Snap.svg.

I select an SVG element by doing the following:

```
on(self.element, 'mousemove', function (e) {

   var item = null;

   if (item === null) {
       item = paper.use(paper.select('#myId')); //Create svg
   }

   var itemBBox = item.getBBox();
   itemBBox.x //returns 0
   itemBBox.y //returns 0
   itemBBox.height //returns 0
   itemBBox.width //returns 0

}
```

My html looks like:

```
<svg>
    <symbol id="myId"><path ...></path></symbol>
</svg>
```

So each variable in itemBBox is 0, unless I add this to a group: `paper.group(itemBBox)`

Why is this and is it required to add single items to a group to be able to fetch the size of a selection?

Comment: Elements need to be part of the DOM to get the bounding box of them.

Comment: That is true. But still I don't understand this, because I think paper.use adds the element to the DOM. It is visible on the screen. And why does grouping it works?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can see what you are actually doing. The code you have posted doesn't really show much.

Comment: On Firefox you can't get the bounding box of a symbol. Not sure about other browsers. You'd have to point a use element at the symbol and get the bounding box of the use element.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointing a use element at the symbol'?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement